# Drivers, Module - Kernel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, kernel-modules

Can somebody explain to me what is a character driver? Can somebody explain to me what is a character driver? Can somebody explain to me what is a character driver?

Answer (score 1):

A "character driver" is a "character device driver", a device driver for a character device (such as a terminal).  A "character device" is a special device which is intended for programs to read and/or write in one or more characters. Any Unix-like system has those present as special devices in `/dev`.

For example:

```
/dev/console
/dev/tty
/dev/null
/dev/zero
```

The device driver is the program which makes the special device work.

Further reading:

- [9.3. Character Devices](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/arch-handbook/driverbasics-char.html) (FreeBSD)
- [4.1. Character Device Drivers](http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x569.html) (The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide)
- [Writing a Linux Kernel Module — Part 2: A Character Device](http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-2-a-character-device/)